# Mask / Zero out area outside specified ROI

Tags: templates, opencv, matching

I'm working on a project using OpenCV on template matching, and I want to limit the search region on an image. Image is captured continuously from a camera.

Is there any way to Zero / mask out image outside ROI defined, so that template matching process can be specific on remaining region, faster and accurate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [cvSetImageROI](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=setimageroi#cvSetImageROI) function.

> `void cvSetImageROI(IplImage*  image,
>   CvRect  rect)`
>
> Sets an image Region Of Interest (ROI) for a given rectangle.
>   Parameters:
>
> - image – A pointer to the image header
> - rect – The ROI rectangle
>
> If the original image ROI was NULL and
>   the rect is not the whole image, the
>   ROI structure is allocated.
>
> Most OpenCV functions support the use
>   of ROI and treat the image rectangle
>   as a separate image. For example, all
>   of the pixel coordinates are counted
>   from the top-left (or bottom-left)
>   corner of the ROI, not the original
>   image.

Answer (score 1):

You use cvSetImageROI to set the region of interest. The template matching functions use only the ROI you set (and ignore whatever is outside it)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Managed to get it running. Thanks.