# How can I compare images of the same origin that were cropped?

Tags: image-processing, image-comparison

Suppose I have an image file/URL, and I want my software to search it within a set of up to 100 images (or at least in that order of magnitude). The target image that the software should find should be the "same" image as the given image, but it should still be able to "forgive" slight processing on either of them (the two images may have been cropped differently, or they were compressed differently).
The question is - is this feasible a task, given that I won't have any of the images before the search is taking place (i.e., there won't be any indexing prior to the search.) Is it likely to work in subsecond time (remember that the compare set is quite small). And if feasible, which tools can I use for this task? This could be software components or even an online service (I can live with that for a proof of concept). Can [OpenSURF](http://www.chrisevansdev.com/computer-vision-opensurf.html) help me here?
To focus my question further - I'm not asking which algorithms to use, at this point I would rather use an existing tool/API/service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The target image that the software should find should be the "same" image as the given image, but it should still be able to "forgive" slight processing on either of them.

If "slight processing" doesn't involve rotation, but only "cropping", then simple cross-correlation should work, if there could be perspective correction, rotation, lens distortion correction, then things are more complicated.

I think this method is quite forgiving to slight color corrections. Anyway, you can always convert both images to grayscale and compare grayscale versions if you want.

> To focus my question further - I'm not asking which algorithms to use, at this point I would rather use an existing tool/API/service.

You can start from [`cvMatchTemplate`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_object_detection.html#matchtemplate) from OpenCV library (the link points to the C version of the API, but it's available also for C++ and Python). Use the cropped image as a template, and look for it in all your images.

If the images you compare have dark features on light backgrounds, you may benefit from using `CV_TM_CCOEFF` or `CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED` methods. They both subtract the average over the template area from both images. Normalized methods (`CV_TM_*_NORMED`) generally work better but are slower than their non-normalized counterparts.

You may consider to do some preprocessing with the images before the cross-correlation. If you normalize them first, the cross-correlation will be less sensitive to slight brightness/contrast modification. If you detect edges first, as suggested by @misha, you'll lose color/lightness information, but the results for contour overlapping will be much better.

Answer (score 1):

jetxee set you off on the right track.  However, if you simply use template matching, you can run into problems where the background interferes with your template matching result.  For example, if your template is a building and your background is primarily light (e.g. desert sand), then the template matching will fail because the lighter background will always return a higher cross-correlation than the darker template.  Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761940/opencv-template-matching-and-transparency) of this problem.

The way you solve it is the same as what is in the link:

- Perform edge-detection on both your template and the target image.
- Throw original template and image away
- Perform template detection using the edge-detected template and edge-detected target image

As far as forgiving slight processing, the edge detection step will take care of that.  As long as the edges in the two images are not modified significantly (blurred, optically distorted), the approach will work.

Comment: Valid points. However, when using `cvMatchTemplate` directly, one can avoid the problem of bright backgrounds if he uses `CV_TM_CCOEFF` or `CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED` methods. They both subtract the average over the template area from both images. I, personally, like to cross-correlate after edge detection, but it is not always the best solution, because the color/lightness information is lost; this way one cannot distinguish between, for example, a white circle on a black background and a black circle on a white background.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I haven't used those parameters before.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are not looking specifically for algorithms, but nonetheless, let me suggest the following which can accomplish exactly what you are trying to do, very efficiently...

For cropped versions of the same image, including rotation, the F[ourier-Mellin transform](http://www.scribd.com/doc/9480198/Tools-FourierMellin-Transform) or a [log-polar transform](http://machineawakening.blogspot.com/2009/07/python-implementation-of-log-polar.html) (watch out for the artsy semi-nude drawing - good source however) will give you the translation, rotation and scale coefficients between the two images, allowing to to determine what operations were needed to go from one to the other.

Comment: Good links! +1 for Fourier-Mellin.