# Template Matching with Python 3.9.1, opencv.python 4.5.1.48 and mask (transparency)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, transparency, mask, template-matching

I had the same problem as this question since 2J, but none of the answers worked with Python 3, so today I took all day to solve the problem:
[python opencv cv2 matchTemplate with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642497/python-opencv-cv2-matchtemplate-with-transparency) (graphics taken from the question)
I finally managed to write a cv2.matchTemplate() with mask (transparency / alpha channel) and python (3.9.1) and opencv-python (4.5.1.48).

The problem was that I passed the mask as RGBA (RGB as zeros) as in Python 2, and always found (0,0) as the location, because all values of the result were always zero.
When I then tried to pass only the alpha channel, it worked as expected!
Because I didn't find anything about the topic with Python 3, I write a new question, hoping to get some suggestions for improvement.
I have written two functions in my code, one to traditionally find only one location (`findImgLoc()`). The other (`findImgTresh()`) to get all coordinates where the value is above the threshold. **Both functions normalize (0 - 1) all methods and invert the result of SQDIFF and SQDIFF NORMED**, so you get only the coordinates back, or in the 2nd case a list of coordinates, which is in my opinion more beginner friendly. For testing I have a `test()` function to get the output graphics and information in the cmd output.
**And just because I read this again and again in old answers, with the code the mask works with all matching methods, not only with TM_SQDIFF and TM_CCORR_NORMED!**

**Image**

[image: Source Image]

**Template**

[image: Template Image]

**Result without mask** *(`findImgTresh()` with `SQDIFF_NORMED` und `thres=.95` -> **4 locations**)*

*Output:* `[[15, 123], [15, 124], [15, 165], [15, 166]]`

[image: Result without mask]

**Result with mask** *(`findImgTresh()` with `SQDIFF_NORMED` und `thres=.95` -> **2 locations**)*

*Output:* `[[15, 123], [15, 165]]`

[image: Result with mask]

**Result without mask on image**

[image: Result without mask on image]

**Result with mask on image**

[image: Result with mask on image]

**Code**

```
import cv2, os
import numpy as np


# Method: 0: SQDIFF | 1: SQDIFF NORMED | 2: TM CCORR | 3: TM CCORR NORMED | 4: TM COEFF | 5: TM COEFF NORMED
img_path = "/Path/to/your/file/source_image_name.png"
tem_path = "/Path/to/your/file/template_image_name.png"


def findImgLoc(image_path, template_path, mask=False, method=1):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # cv2.IMREAD_COLOR (cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    tem = cv2.imread(tem_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # cv2.IMREAD_COLOR (cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    # Match template with and without mask
    if mask and img.shape[2] == 4:
        alpha_channel = np.array(cv2.split(tem)[3])
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tem, method, mask=alpha_channel)

    else:
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tem, method)

    # Nomrmalize result data to percent (0-1)
    result = cv2.normalize(result, None, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, -1)

    # Invert Image to work similar across all methods!
    if method == 0 or method == 1: result = (1 - result)
    _minVal, _maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result, None)

    matchLoc = maxLoc

    # Make the Result viewable
    # view_result = cv2.normalize(result, None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
    cv2.rectangle(result, matchLoc, (matchLoc[0] + tem.shape[0], matchLoc[1] + tem.shape[1]), (255,0,0), 2)

    return matchLoc

def findImgthres(image_path, template_path, mask=False, method=1, thres=.95):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # cv2.IMREAD_COLOR (cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    tem = cv2.imread(tem_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # cv2.IMREAD_COLOR (cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    # Match template with and without mask
    if mask and img.shape[2] == 4:
        alpha_channel = np.array(cv2.split(tem)[3])
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tem, method, mask=alpha_channel)

    else:
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tem, method)

    # Nomrmalize result data to percent (0-1)
    result = cv2.normalize(result, None, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, -1)
    
    # Invert Image to work similar across all methods!
    if method == 0 or method == 1: result = (1 - result)

    result_list = np.argwhere(result > thres)

    return result_list

def test():
    global img_path, tem_path

    def findImgthres(image_path, template_path, mask=False, method=1, thres=.95):
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # cv2.IMREAD_COLOR (cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        tem = cv2.imread(tem_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # cv2.IMREAD_COLOR (cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

        # Match template with and without mask
        if mask and img.shape[2] == 4:
            alpha_channel = np.array(cv2.split(tem)[3])
            result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tem, method, mask=alpha_channel)

        else:
            result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tem, method)

        # Nomrmalize result data to percent (0-1)
        result = cv2.normalize(result, None, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, -1)
        
        # Invert Image to work similar across all methods!
        if method == 0 or method == 1: result = (1 - result)

        result_list = np.argwhere(result > thres)

        return result, result_list

    tmp_source = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    tmp_mask_source = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    tmp_tem = cv2.imread(tem_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    result = findImgthres(img_path, tem_path)
    mask_result = findImgthres(img_path, tem_path, mask=True)

    # Mark original Image with mask
    matchLoc = mask_result[1]
    if matchLoc is not None:
        for loc in matchLoc:
            cv2.rectangle(tmp_mask_source, tuple(loc)[::-1], (loc[1] + tmp_tem.shape[1], loc[0] + tmp_tem.shape[0]), (0,0,0), 1)

    # Mark original Image without mask
    matchLoc = result[1]
    if matchLoc is not None:
        for loc in matchLoc:
            cv2.rectangle(tmp_source, tuple(loc)[::-1], (loc[1] + tmp_tem.shape[1], loc[0] + tmp_tem.shape[0]), (0,0,0), 1)

    # Save Images
    _dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(_dir, "source.png") , tmp_source)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(_dir, "mask_source.png") , tmp_mask_source)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(_dir, "result.png") , 255*result[0])
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(_dir, "mask_result.png") , 255*mask_result[0])

    # Output Result
    print(f"[NO MASK] Match Locs: {result[1]}")
    print(f"[MASK] Match Locs: {mask_result[1]}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

**I hope I could help further and am happy about suggestions for improvement!**