# python opencv matchTemplate is mask feature implemented?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

[OpenCV, as of version 3.0.0, added a mask feature](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/3554) to the matchTemplate method. It supports template matching with transparent templates by defining a mask on the template. My python program below works fine, but if I add a `mask` parameter to the `cv2.matchTemplate` call, it throws an error:

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented () in matchTemplateMask, file /Users/jared.rada/dev/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp, line 894
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "masked.py", line 13, in <module>
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tmpl, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, data, mask)
cv2.error: /Users/jared.rada/dev/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:894: error: (-213)  in function matchTemplateMask`
```

My source code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = cv2.imread('./image.jpg')
tmpl = cv2.imread('./tmpl.png')
mask = cv2.imread('./mask.png')
w, h = tmpl.shape[:-1]
data = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tmpl, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, data, mask)

min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
cv2.rectangle(img, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([img]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**How do I know if the python bindings support the mask feature?**

Comment: you might be wrong about the version, if it was merged  on jan 19, it's probably in opencv3.1 only.

Comment: yes good point @berak, i also tried 3.1.0 (confirmed by `print cv2.__version__` which reads `3.1.0` but it throws the same error. any other suggestions on how i can find out if this feature is implemented in the python bindings?

Comment: i looked at the .cpp file mentioned in the error, and i see this signature `static bool matchTemplate_CCOEFF_NORMED(InputArray _image, InputArray _templ, OutputArray _result)` so it appears there is no parameter for the mask.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there is an easy answer: looking at the [src code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp#L866) , you will find, that it's only implemented for `method == CV_TM_SQDIFF` and `method == CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED` , in other words, not for your desired `cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED`

Comment: Out of date. Please update.

Answer (score 7):

update for the answer: see [src code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/524a2fffe96195b906a95b548b0a185d3251eb7e/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp#L762)

and [the commit](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/15214):

**templmatch: Add support for mask for all methods**

now latest `pip install opencv-contrib-python` will including mask for all methods (testd on python3.7(