# Matching template images with masks using OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, mask, matching, matchtemplate

**How can I match a masked image using matchTemplate() in OpenCV with C++?**

This is my masked template image:

[image]

And this is my source image:

[image]

Comment: May be this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761940/opencv-template-matching-and-transparency

Answer (score 2):

`matchTemplate`'s fifth argument is a `mask` array which you can use for this purpose. In your case, you'll want a *binary* mask. That is, a `Mat` with:

- depth `CV_8U`, and
- dimensions equal to your template image, and
- the pixels you want to *ignore* from your template set to 0, and
- the pixels you want to be used set to a non-zero value (typically 1)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [opencv example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html). You gotta call the `matchTemplate` function:

```
matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
```

Comment: @Sadir: I looked at that example and I used matchTemplate() before, but I would like to know the best way to match a template image that is masked.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by > "I would like to know the best way to match a template image that is masked".

Comment: If you look at the template image in my question you will see that it has black pixels. In a masked image, the black pixels will be "transparent", and only the pixels with values > 0 will be taken into consideration when matching.

Comment: `matchTemplate` does something like convolution, it slides the windows over the image and applies the convolution. So, I don't think it's possible to specify the template image as "mask" the way you want it.