# matchTemplate with non-rectangular templ

Tags: opencv, template-matching

Is there some way for [`matchTemplate`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html#matchtemplate) to work with a non-rectangular `templ`? For example to use the alpha channel, etc to ignore certain pixels when calculating the score?

The [various formulas](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=method#matchtemplate) for scores SHOULD generalize to non-rectangular templates.

Comment: might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761940/opencv-template-matching-and-transparency

Comment: This is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16029844/1709587; the short answer is to use the `mask` parameter to `matchTemplate`. I can't VTC as a dupe because my answer there has no upvotes, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using openCV 3 you can use mask to do template match on non-rectangular regions.

But in case you are using openCV 2, you have to write your own function to mask your template and then do template match on the source image.