# How to programmatically fill in RGB noise in the transparent region of an image using Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, simplecv, template-matching

I need to process a lot of images using Python. All these images have some transparent region (alpha channel) of different sizes.

I need to programmatically fill in RGB noise in the transparent region of those images, but keep the non-transparent region unchanged. [This is an example of changing the images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761940/opencv-template-matching-and-transparency/20461136#20461136).

How to do this programmatically in Python?

Comment: Make a new image completely filled with random R,G,B values. Blend the image in question over the top of the random one.

Comment: does this noise have to change for each image?

Comment: slow but simple: `for each pixel: if alpha equals zero: set rgb value to random value and set alpha to 255`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you need to:

1. Create a `Mat` that contains Gaussian noise (or what kind of noise you need to add in the images).
2. For each image you copy the noise `Mat` into another one based on the alpha channel (used as mask)
3. Add the two images (`initial` and `noise_mask`) to he `initial` image (or the `inital_noisy_background`)

Comment: Adding only works if you're using pre-multiplied alpha.