# OpenCv finding similar image

Tags: python, opencv, matchtemplate

I'm trying to play with the match_template in opencv,

i try to match this two image,

this is the image > https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SzBo.jpg

the stars I want to search >https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1vjD.jpg.

The result is over 0.9 which is really good , but when the image change to other monster such as :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUHaA.jpg

the result is 0.5 only 

or when a same monster with more stars such as :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/62O4V.jpg

the result is even higher then other 2star monster

I want to use the star image to search all two stars monster , i tried using 
different matching method in 2 days and I cant really achieve this image serach

Is there any ways/recommendation to help me achieve this kind of image search ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you matching the entire image? If so, and if the stars are always in the same place and the stars are the important aspect, try cropping to just the top-left corner prior to matching.

Comment: I'm using the star to search the monster image . The star image is cropped from the monster image

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the template not with the original images, but with canny edge detection added to both of them, so it should only match the edges of the starts. Maybe even try messing with the color channels, making those stars pop out more from the template/image.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761940/opencv-template-matching-and-transparency) is something more for you to read.